# How to set Speed with network type in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In setting a computing instance for auto scale option, there are public and private network uplinks. When I set the network component, I am setting a speed only. How can I set Private & Public network along with the speed ?

```
// Network Components
Component networkComponent = new Component();
networkComponent.setMaxSpeed(speed);
virtualGuestMemberTemplate.getNetworkComponents().add(networkComponent);
```

[image: seting network component]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've been more explicit with my previous answer, I'm adding the script used for creating a Scale group with the modifications required for setting up a
Virtual Guest Network Component.

I hope this help you.

```
package SoftLayer_Java_Scripts.Examples;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.*;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Location;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.Group;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.guest.network.Component;


public class CreateScaleGroup {

  private static String user = "set me";
  private static String apiKey = "set me";

  private static ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Group.Service scaleGroupService = Group.service(client);

    Location location = new Location();
    location.setName("hkg02");

    // Standard Virtual Guest configuration.
    Guest guest = new Guest();
    guest.setDomain("softlayer.com");
    guest.setHostname("hostnametest");
    guest.setPostInstallScriptUri("https://www.softlayer.com/script");
    guest.setStartCpus(new Long (1));
    guest.setDatacenter(location);
    guest.setHourlyBillingFlag(true);
    guest.setLocalDiskFlag(false);
    guest.setOperatingSystemReferenceCode("CENTOS_LATEST");
    guest.setMaxMemory(new Long (1));

    /*
     * The configuration for SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component 
     * depends on combinations of the network component max speed 
     * and the virtual guest privateNetworkOnlyFlag.
     * 
     * The available configurations are:
     * 1.- Network maxSpeed (  10) Guest privateNetworkOnlyFlag (false) for "10 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
     * 2.- Network maxSpeed ( 100) Guest privateNetworkOnlyFlag (false) for "100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
     * 3.- Network maxSpeed (1000) Guest privateNetworkOnlyFlag (false) for "1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
     * 4.- Network maxSpeed (  10) Guest privateNetworkOnlyFlag ( true) for "10 Mbps Private Network Uplink"
     * 5.- Network maxSpeed ( 100) Guest privateNetworkOnlyFlag ( true) for "100 Mbps Private Network Uplink"
     * 6.- Network maxSpeed (1000) Guest privateNetworkOnlyFlag ( true) for "1 Gbps Private Network Uplink"   
     */
    Component networkComponent = new Component();
    networkComponent.setMaxSpeed(new Long(100));
    guest.getNetworkComponents().add(networkComponent);
    guest.setPrivateNetworkOnlyFlag(false);

    // Standard scale group configuration.
    Group scaleGroup = new Group();
    scaleGroup.setCooldown(new Long(1800));
    scaleGroup.setMaximumMemberCount(new Long(5));
    scaleGroup.setMinimumMemberCount(new Long(1));
    scaleGroup.setName("testVSI");
    scaleGroup.setRegionalGroupId(new Long(102));
    scaleGroup.setSuspendedFlag(false);
    scaleGroup.setTerminationPolicyId(new Long(2));
    scaleGroup.setVirtualGuestMemberTemplate(guest);
    scaleGroup.setVirtualGuestMemberCount(new Long(0));

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(scaleGroupService.createObject(scaleGroup)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `networkComponent.setPrivateNetworkOnlyFlag(true);` to only use Private Network Uplink. Setting up that to false allows Public & Private Network Uplinks.

Also, you can use this script to check the available speed values.

```
package SoftLayer_Java_Scripts.Examples;

import java.util.List;

import com.softlayer.api.*;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.guest.network.Component;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.virtual.guest.Configuration;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.virtual.guest.configuration.Option;

public class GetNetworkComponentsTemplates {

  private static String user = "set me";
  private static String apiKey = "set me";

  private static ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey);

  public static void main( String[] args ) {

    Guest.Service virtualGuestService = Guest.service(client);

    try
    {
      Configuration config =  virtualGuestService.getCreateObjectOptions();
      List<Option> options = config.getNetworkComponents();

      for(Option option : options) {
        String description = option.getItemPrice().getItem().getDescription();
        List<Component> networkComponents = option.getTemplate().getNetworkComponents();
        long maxSpeed = 0L;
        for(Component network : networkComponents) {
          maxSpeed = network.getMaxSpeed();
        }
        System.out.println("*** Network Component ***");
        System.out.println("Description: " + description);
        System.out.println("Max Speed: " + maxSpeed + "\n");
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Script failed, review the next message for further details: " + e); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No.. there is no method of "setPrivateNetworkOnlyFlag(true)" in networkcomponent. ("SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component")